# Windows minecraft on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, executable, minecraft

I've got a Minecraft version for Windows, which runs with an .exe file. I've tried to make it run with java directly and it didn't an Ubuntu message appears "Fatal: Read Error: Could not read or parse the JNLP file" (Show more details), when I tried with Wine, a Wine message appears "No JVM could be found on your system. Please define EXE4J_JAVA_HOME to point to an installed 32-bit JDK or JRE or download a JRE from www.java.com
Is there a way I can make it run? It's all because I cannot make the mods work on my Minecraft's Linux version
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to install a **windows version** of **Java** in **wine**, not sure if winetricks supplies it. This is according to an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/240365/how-do-i-run-a-program-in-ubuntu-using-wine-that-requires-jre) which further refers to [winehq - java](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1372)

You can try this and see if it fixes your issue

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found: 
[How do we install Java in Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117041/how-do-we-install-java-in-wine)

But I don't have any problems with mods on my linux machine so I'm wondering if there could be another problem. Do you have Forge or ModLoader installed? I would make sure the JDK is fully up to date on the linux machine, Forge updated, Minecraft updated, etc.

The minecraft EXE is a relatively new development and everything ran off of the same .jar file previously; there really isn't a difference in the program, I believe it's something to do with your software or OS.