# Installing JDK with wine

Tags: jdk

So I have installed Unity3D with wine and it works but when i try to build it says "Unable to find suitable JDK installation". I have installed JDK and it works with Android Studio. I think the problem is that i need to install the JDK thru wine so it can work with Unity.I don't know how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the latest [windows version from there website](http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)

When it is finished right click it and choose open with wine.

Comment: Installed it, when i try to open it with wine it just loads for 5-10 seconds and stops. Nothing happens.

Comment: So it installed fine ? You don't need to open Java once it is installed, just run unity 3D and it should work now

Comment: Also wine sucks, it is not reliable and using it is not recommended due to huge compatibility issues, have you seen this http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Running_Unity_on_Linux_through_Wine

Comment: So if it is installed where can i find it ?

Comment: Goto your home folder, press ctrl + H to show hidden files and find the .wine folder, in here is an emulated windows C:/ with a programfiles folder just like real windows

Comment: OK Thanks ill search. Any idea where it is by default?

Comment: I don't have installed but to guess /home/Username/.wine/Drive_C/program files/JRE7 or something very close to that

Comment: Hi again. Any idea why it wouldn't work ? it displays the same error

Comment: Sorry  for late reply, read the first answer here it may help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/117041/how-do-we-install-java-in-wine