# Running .exe file got me a blank window in wine

Tags: software-installation, wine, jre

I want to run an .exe program, but when I try it requests Java Runtime 1.8:

[image: Message requiring JRE 1.8.0]

So I searched for how to install this in wine, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117041/how-do-we-install-java-in-wine), but when trying to install JRE I got a blank page, like this:

[image: Blank window to install JRE]

And I'm unable to install it. There is any way to show installation setup or install JRE 1.8.0 without a GUI?

When I try to run it in the terminal I got this:

```
arthur@rogadonitro:~/Downloads$ wine JavaSetup8u401.exe 
0110:err:winediag:ntlm_check_version ntlm_auth was not found. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0110:err:ntlm:ntlm_LsaApInitializePackage no NTLM support, expect problems
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
011c:err:mshtml:create_document_object Failed to init Gecko, returning CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE
```

I tried solve these errors, but the Gecko problem is not solved. How I can do this?